# I want to create a array without if() of for() but use where()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm solving some problems and it asked me 
"In Python solve these problems with where() in Numpy without using for() or if()"
There is two arrays First one is

```
[1,2,3,5,3,4,3,6,9,7,0,8,7,10]
```

Second one is

```
[7,2,10,5,7,4,9,1,8,0,3,7,6]
```

And results of One is "In two arrays have both same values [2 5 4 9 0 7]" other one is In two arrays have both same Index(array([1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12])) 
So I need to find these condition as same values with in Index
I tried solve it. But I don't figure out how to find both. I mean I found Index but couldn't found both.

Comment: The two arrays are not equal in the places you describe, and they are of different lengths. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the arrays are of equal length. Then you can use `==` to do an elementwise comparison

```
a == b
# array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False, False])
```

get the equal values using

```
b[a == b]
# array([2, 5, 4])
```

and the the indices using

```
np.where(a == b)[0]
# array([1, 3, 5])
```

Comment: Yes those are equal length and I have to find  index and values so need to output as same as the results values and index.

Comment: @WooYeol Lee. To get the results you expect the second array needs to be changed.  The `4, 9, 1` in position [5:8] needs to be `4, x, 1, 9` where x isn't 3.  Then the answer above will give the results you expect.